# sqlite numeric value in string field causes InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net

I have a SQLite table with the following definition:

```
create table routes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name string)
```

and want to fetch records using [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/):

```
cmdRoute.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM routes";
using (var rdrRoute = cmdRoute.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(rdrRoute.Read())
    {
        var route = new Route();
        route.Id = rdrRoute.GetInt32(0);
        route.Name = rdrRoute.GetString(1); // Throws InvalidCastException
    }
}
```

The GetString throws an InvalidCastException when the value in the database is numeric.
When I put the `rdrRoute.GetValue(1)` in a watch, it shows that the type is "object {string}". When I change the value to a non-numeric value, it works fine.

I've looked in the [SQLite DataReader code](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/artifact/5ca6e5449b25f7e8d8948cb02d5310b8c57b8b75) and it looks like SQLite checks the value to map it to a set of allowed types.

Is this the intended behaviour and how can I prevent this, in a way that strings containing numbers are still strings?

Comment: Luuk how about if you try this `route.Name = rdrRoute.GetString(1).ToString();` or try casting it as a string like this 
`route.Name = (string)rdrRoute.GetString(1);`

Comment: `rdrRoute.GetString(1)` already crashes with the InvalidCastException.

Comment: did you try it with casting as a string `(string)rdrRoute.GetString(1);`

Comment: `(string)rdrRoute.GetValue(1)` works, but I want to know why the `GetString(1)` doesn't work.

Comment: I know why you're getting error and I will add this to my answer as well for better readability and explanation.

Comment: Luuk I look at the example , could use if you wanted to do the ISDBNull check which you should actually use

Comment: Data is not null, GetString crashes if the value in the database is "1234", and does not crash if the value is "banana"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23711/discussion-between-dj-kraze-and-luuk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for the SqlDataReader.GetString Method, No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.`

`Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.`

Change you code to this and it should work

```
cmdRoute.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM routes";
using (var rdrRoute = cmdRoute.ExecuteReader())
{
    if(rdrRoute.Read())
    {
        var route = new Route();
        route.Id  = rdrRoute["id"];
        if (!rdrRoute.IsDBNull(rdrRoute.GetOrdinal("name")))
        {
           route.Name = rdrRoute["name"].ToString();
           //route.Name = rdrRoute.GetString(rdrRount.GetOrdinal("name"));
           //may not work in .Net 4.0
        }
    }
}
```

.NET 4.0 GetString() may cause errors / bugs in .NET 4.0 I would try rolling the project back to ver 3.5 or create a project that uses the code sample and create it as .NET 3.5, if this works with the `GetString()` I have found that there are some bugs in .net 4.0 and I am not sure when the KB Fix is going to release

Comment: `(string)rdrRoute.GetString(1)` crashes with InvalidCastException, and the Id is an Int32, so I need to convert it with `Convert.ToInt32(rdrRoute["id"])`. `rdrRoute["name"].ToString();` works though.